# Mysql getting rows by each month in each year

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to find the sum of cost for each month in each year.

I have the below table 'logs'

```
date               |    cost
---------------------------------
Wed, 01 Aug 2016   |    45
Tue, 15 Aug 2016   |    52
Mon, 31 Aug 2016   |    23
Thu, 05 Sep 2016   |    9
Sat, 10 Sep 2016   |    33
Mon, 12 Feb 2017   |    8
Tue, 31 Feb 2017   |    0
Wed, 31 Mar 2017   |    100
Fri, 31 Mar 2017   |    35
Thu, 31 Mar 2017   |    45
```

This is what im trying to achive,

### **2017**

**Feb**
8+0

**Mar**
100+35+45

---

### 2016

**Aug**
45+52+23

**Sep**
9+33

---

Currently im doing this,

```
$sqly = "SELECT DISTINCT RIGHT(date,4) as year FROM logs ORDER BY id DESC;";
$resy = mysql_query($sqly);
while($rowy = mysql_fetch_array($resy))
{
   echo $rowy['year'];
}
```

Result:

### **2017**

### **2016**

I dont know how to proceed further to get the months on each year and sum the total for each month.

Comment: edit in your query and also parse the month

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should work:

```
SELECT YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(date, '%W, %d %M %Y')) AS year,
       MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(date, '%W, %d %M %Y')) AS month, 
       SUM(cost) 
FROM logs 
GROUP BY year, month;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query.

```
SELECT YEAR(date) AS year, MONTH(date) AS month, COUNT(DISTINCT id) FROM logs GROUP BY year, month
```

Comment: Im getting Year & Month as NULL and the count of entries.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use below code to find your answer, Hope this will help you

<?php

$sqly = "SELECT DISTINCT RIGHT(date,4) as year FROM logs ORDER BY id DESC;";
$resy = mysql_query($sqly);
while($rowy = mysql_fetch_array($resy))
{
   echo $rowy['year'];

   $sqly2 = "select SUBSTRING(date, 9, 3) as month_name, Group_concat(cost,' + ') as total_cost from logs where RIGHT(date,4) = '".$rowy['year']."' GROUP BY SUBSTRING(date, 9, 3)";
    $resy2 = mysql_query($sqly2);

    while($rowy2 = mysql_fetch_array($resy2))
{
   echo $rowy2['month_name'] ." ".$rowy2['total_cost'] ;

}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.